# Rails 4 doesn't recognize "application/json" DocumentType from Backbone model.save()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, backbone.js

TLDR of the question: In case 1, I can't get params. In case 2, I can get params. How can I get params in Case 1?

Case 1: Doesn't work: Backbone's model.save() attempting to use "application/json" DocumentType

Note that `Backbone.emulateJSON = true;` is commented out.

**in backbone model**

```
onSubmit: function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // Backbone.emulateJSON = true;

  this.model.set({
    title:         this.$el.find('#input-title').val(),
    href:          this.$el.find('#input-href').val(),
    tags:          this.$el.find('#input-tags').val(),
    suggestedTags: this.$el.find('#input-suggested-tags').val(),
    comment:       this.$el.find('#input-comment').val()
  });

  this.model.save();

  Backbone.history.navigate('#', true);
}
```

**in rails console**

```rb
def link_params
  debugger
  params.require(:model).permit(:title, :href, :comment)
end
```

** debugging results **

```
(rdb:1) request.format.json?
false

(rdb:1) request.body.read
""

(rdb:1) request.parameters
{"controller"=>"api/v0/links", "action"=>"options"}

(rdb:1) request.format
#<Mime::Type:0x00000106f6f840 @synonyms=[], @symbol=nil, @string="*/*">

  ...
```

Note that in `request.env["rack.session.options"]`, Mime type correctly says application/json. But `request.format` doesn't recognize json.

Case 2: This works in the sense that i can get params.

**in backbone model**

```
onSubmit: function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  Backbone.emulateJSON = true;

  this.model.set({
    title:         this.$el.find('#input-title').val(),
    href:          this.$el.find('#input-href').val(),
    tags:          this.$el.find('#input-tags').val(),
    suggestedTags: this.$el.find('#input-suggested-tags').val(),
    comment:       this.$el.find('#input-comment').val()
  });

  this.model.save();

  Backbone.history.navigate('#', true);
}
```

**debugger results **

```
(rdb:1) request.format
#<Mime::Type:0x000001019ce940 @synonyms=["application/xhtml+xml"], @symbol=:html, @string="text/html">

(rdb:1) request.format.json?
false

(rdb:1) request.format.html?
true

(rdb:1)  request.body.read
"model=%7B%22href%22%3A%22wrg%22%2C%22tags%22%3A%22wrg%22%2C%22title%22%3A%22awrgawrga%22%2C%22suggestedTags%22%3A%22wrgwrg%22%2C%22comment%22%3A%22wrg%22%7D"

(rdb:1) request.parameters
{"model"=>"{\"href\":\"wrg\",\"tags\":\"wrg\",\"title\":\"awrgawrga\",\"suggestedTags\":\"wrgwrg\",\"comment\":\"wrg\"}", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"api/v0/links"}

(rdb:1) request.format
#<Mime::Type:0x000001019ce940 @synonyms=["application/xhtml+xml"], @symbol=:html, @string="text/html">
```

Notes--

I added `Mime::Type.register "application/json", :json` in mime_types.rb initializer.

Rails 4.1.4

ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-darwin12.0]